# Prepacking files with iOS ipa

Tags: ios, ipa

I'm building a new in-app purchase App. My in-apps are downloading properly, which are mp3 files. I'm moving these to my apps "documents/download/mp3" folder

I want to prepackage a few free mp3 files along with the ipa. I've tried creating directories within the app and importing them. Can't seem to get a hang of this. A little nudge in the right direction will be much appreciated.

Thanks
Tushar

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the files into your "Project". You can then choose whether you copy the files from the bundle into the directory like normal. Or use the files from the bundle itself.

Comment: Hmm, That's a little bit of pain isn't it. Can I add a full directory structure to zip and then unzip it on my first run? This is just a test project, but I want to build the framework to support multiple files for the future.

Comment: There should be some open source zipping/unzipping frameworks out there that might be able to unzip with directories, but without additional research I cannot say for certain.

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

http://corporationunknown.com/blog/2014/07/10/preloading-development-data-into-your-ios-app/

You can package your data as xcappdata packages. Do not add them to targets. But in your run configuration, you can attach them and application data. You can then add files and folders as you need to the xcappdata in the Finder.

I'm still dealing with other issues of SSZipArchive, but it's so much fun learning this way. Cheers All. Hope the solution works. Its working for me.

Comment: Note that xcappdata packages are useful for development only.  If the OP is trying to find a solution that can eventually be deployed to the AppStore, this won't work at all.